# Parse XML with a specific parent tag

Tags: python, xml, parsing

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <ReturnHeader>
    <Bob>
      <Age>39</Age>
      <PhoneNum>2222</PhoneNum>
    </Bob>
    <John>
      <Age>70</Age>
      <PhoneNum>4444</PhoneNum>
    </John>
  </ReturnHeader>
```

From the above XML, I'm trying to get only the phone of Bob. (i.e., when Bob is 'True).

I need the following output:

PhoneNum 2222

I tried lxml with Xpath, but no luck. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "no luck" - What is the specific problem? This looks like a rather simple XML task.

Comment: I can get the data, but not under specific tag (Bob in this case). There might be multiple such tags, but I need age only if it’s under Bob.

Comment: Please always include what you've tried in your question, so that people see that you are not just lazy and try to get others to do your work, but also what didn't work (and why), so that people don't try to recommend something you already tried. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <ReturnHeader>
    <Bob>
      <Age>39</Age>
      <PhoneNum>2222</PhoneNum>
    </Bob>
    <John>
      <Age>70</Age>
      <PhoneNum>4444</PhoneNum>
    </John>
  </ReturnHeader>'''

NAME_TO_FIND = 'Bob'
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
for ele in root:
  if ele.tag == NAME_TO_FIND:
    print(f'The phone number of {NAME_TO_FIND} is {ele.find("PhoneNum").text}')
  else:
    print(f'I am not interested in the phone number of {ele.tag}')
```

output

```
The phone number of Bob is 2222
I am not interested in the phone number of John
```

Comment: Thanks @balderman. It worked. Based on your solution, I've a slightly different issue and have created a new question. Would appreciate if you can help me with this as well. Here is the question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71391131/18379466