# XML parsing under a specific parent tag

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <ReturnHeader>
    <Bob>
      <PhoneNum>2222</PhoneNum>
      <Address>
        <AddressLine1>111 St</AddressLine1>
        <Zip>999</Zip>
      </Address>
    </Bob>
    <John>
      <PhoneNum>4444</PhoneNum>
      <Address>
        <AddressLine1>222 Ln</AddressLine1>
        <Zip>777</Zip> 
      </Address>    
    </John>
  </ReturnHeader>
```

From the above XML, I'm trying to get the ZIP Code of Bob. I need the following output:

Bob 999

Based on an answer here, I'm using the following code. But I can't get the text inside the address. Any help is appreciated.

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

NAME_TO_FIND = 'Bob'
root = ET.fromstring(xml)
for ele in root:
  if ele.tag == NAME_TO_FIND:
    print(ele.find("Zip").text)
```

Comment: but zip code of Bob is 999?

Comment: My bad. I've edited the question.

Comment: Hint: `Zip` is a grandchild of `Bob`, not a direct child.

Comment: Are you *sure* that you have elements that are literally called `<Bob>` and `<John>` in your XML? Because that would be extremely unusual. I suspect you've tried to simplify your XML and went one step too far.

Comment: No, the xml I've is too long (runs for few pages). I simplified it so that I can understand the logic behind the solution.

Comment: That was not my question. Are those elements *really* named `<Bob>` and `<John>` (i.e. "each child of `<ReturnHeader>` has a unique name that consists of relevant data"), or are they named `<Person>` and `"Bob"` is merely a data point beneath `<Person>`? I suspect the latter is the case, and renaming the elements randomly was your own idea for the sake of the sample.

Comment: That’s a good question. I just checked back and those name tags are unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use xpath with [iterfind()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.iterfind)

```
name = 'Bob'
zip_code = next(root.iterfind(f'./{name}/Address/Zip'), None)
if zip_code is not None:
    print(zip_code.text) #999

name = 'John'
zip_code = next(root.iterfind(f'./{name}/Address/Zip'), None)
if zip_code is not None:
    print(zip_code.text) #777
```